# Ordering in each column in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to order like this:

```
|-------| |--------| |-------| |-------| |---------|
1. item    4. item    7. item   10. item  13. item
2. item    5. item    8. item   11. item  14. item
3. item    6. item    9. item   12. item  15. item
```

Diving row is not my problem. Just numbering serially.

Code added.

```css
       ol li.list-group-item {
            list-style: decimal inside;
            display: list-item;
        }

        .list-group-item
        {
            border: 0px!important;
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Tom</title>

    <style>
        ol li.list-group-item {
            list-style: decimal inside;
            display: list-item;
        }

        .list-group-item
        {
            border: 0px!important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <h6 class="center">The following are all the <bold>Merit Badges</bold> currently offered by the Boy Scouts of America: </h6>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="list-group">
                <ol class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">American Business</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">American Cultures</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item font-weight-bold">Citizenship in the Community</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Climbing</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="list-group">
                <ol class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">American Business</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">American Cultures</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item font-weight-bold">Citizenship in the Community</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Climbing</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="list-group">
                <ol class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">American Business</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">American Cultures</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item font-weight-bold">Citizenship in the Community</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Climbing</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="list-group">
                <ol class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">American Business</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">American Cultures</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item font-weight-bold">Citizenship in the Community</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Climbing</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="list-group">
                <ol class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">American Business</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">American Cultures</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item font-weight-bold">Citizenship in the Community</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Climbing</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>

</div>




<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is poorly formatted. Please share the code of what you have tried so we can help. But I suggest you use Flexbox CSS to achieve this.

Comment: I have tried just dividing column. But numbering is problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the autonumbers, you can use an ordered list. Flexbox column and wrap makes it easy to get the columns. I tried this with the simplest

```
ol.listNumber {
    column-count: 5;
}
```

but that gets rid of the numbering.

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}

ol.listNumber {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 520px) {
  ol.listNumber {
    height: 350px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 760px) {
  ol.listNumber {
    height: 250px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  ol.listNumber {
    height: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ol class="listNumber">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li> 
  <li>item</li> 
  <li>item</li> 
  <li>item</li> 
  <li>item</li> 
  <li>item</li> 
  <li>item</li> 
  <li>item</li> 
  <li>item</li> 
  <li>item</li> 
  <li>item</li> 
  <li>item</li> 
  <li>item</li> 
</ol>
```

Comment: Good job. But it's not responsive.

Comment: I have updated the code to add media queries for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think @omukiguy said means you can try the Flexbox layout like this.

```css
.container {
  width: 120px;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row{
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row">
 1. item
  </div>
  <div class="row">
 2. item
  </div>
  <div class="row">
 3. item
  </div>
  <div class="row">
 4. item
  </div>
  <div class="row">
 5. item
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's needed automatically numbering.